# Got error message regarding "Privacy Policy Compliance"

Tags: facebook, privacy, policy

We developed an Facebook application (Canvas, Page-tab and Mobile app) to a customer, at first we didn't include any Privacy Policy in the App Settings. But yesterday we got an warning notice from Facebook saying the following:

> Please update your privacy policy for myFBApp to avoid enforcement action. The URL may be missing or returning an error.
>   Also, be sure your privacy policy displays on your website or app. For more info, refer to Platform Policy II.3 and this external resource: http://www.applicationprivacy.org/platform-requirements/facebook/.

Then we created both an Privacy Policy and an Terms of Service page. Linked it in the settings and then saved.

Now 24 hours later, it's still not fixed. We still got the warning and we are growing anxious and worried that if this is not fixed the application might get shut down.

Some more info about the privacy policy pages:

- We have a nofollow meta tag in the html head, so search engines can't index the pages. (I tried deleting this, though did not change anything)
- The pages get no errors from the Debugger. So I assume that FB can index the pages.
- The pages is on the same domain as I registered in the app settings.
- Both the Privacy Policy and the Terms of Service shows and is linked correctly in the application dialogs.

Is this checked manually for Facebook? Or is it some kind of bug? Do I need to generate a Privacy Policy in english? At the moment ours is in swedish. I have seen some threads on Stack Overflow about this problem but no given solution yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message from Facebook is just a warning. If you've added a Privacy Policy and Terms of Service link to the settings, everything will be fine. The message (Developer Alert) won't disappear unless you archive it / mark it as read.

Unless you got a second warning from Facebook, there is nothing more you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I feel like we can relax somewhat now.

Comment: I've got four warnings from facebook, not only this, People are unable to login through facebook now from my android app.

Comment: What are the warnings you've received from Facebook?