# Facebook Privacy Policy Compliance. Please update your privacy policy

Tags: facebook, privacy-policy

The past few hours i keep getting the following message

> Please update your privacy policy for MY_APP_NAME to avoid enforcement action. **The URL may be missing or returning an error.**
> Also, be sure your privacy policy displays on your website or app. For more info, refer to >Platform Policy II.3 and this external resource: http://www.applicationprivacy.org/platform-requirements/facebook/.

on the guide lines of the submission i get this ..

> These apps are not currently eligible for App Center:
>
> A Page Tab app
> A Desktop web game off of Facebook.com

so why i am eligible for privacy update afterall?? and still i have entered all required info in the app details tab and still get an error of invalid submission

> Before you can submit your app detail page you must first comply with App Center >Guidelines. Please make sure you have specified how your app integrates with Facebook and >have met all the requirements. Click here to update your integration.

i could really use some help instead some negative feedback..as i ve seen in similar questions

and last but not least, i ve not spotted any broken url.. :S

Comment: Just add the Privacy Policy URL in app details page, and save changes. This would fix your issue. No need to submit for App Center.

Comment: i have already done this :S really appreciate your answer..i hope, if the problem still remains, to get an extra warning and not any enforcement meassures..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Got error message regarding "Privacy Policy Compliance"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982886/got-error-message-regarding-privacy-policy-compliance)